# Depth-first and breadth-first search variants

Tags: algorithms, searching

Are there special names for the following?

- two variants of depth first search: 1. the current node is visited before its children; 2. the current node is visited after its children;
- two variants of breadth first search: 1. the current node is visited before its children; 2. the current node is visited after its children.

I wonder why Wikipedia is silent on this subject.

Comment: Why do you think we would need there variants? What do you think they add to BFS or DFS?

Comment: @DreamConspiracy I am going to run a digraph of interrelated "modules". A module may link to other module and I do module traversal either depth-first or breadth-first. I may want to "execute" the modules a module refer to either before of after the current module, as specified by the syntax of the reference.

Comment: Wikipedia is not. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: Why stop there? You could visit the current node *between* its left and right children, or you could visit the current node both before *and* after the children.